# POM.xml showing warnings

Tags: maven, spring-boot

Currently my POM.XML looks like this

```
dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>logger.Demo</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

But as soon as i append the below dependency in my  above pom.xml i get a warning and few of my classes get invalidated

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
```

I get the following warnings in POM.xml
1) Overriding managed version 4.12 for junit
2)Overriding managed version 5.0.6.RELEASE for spring-core

Can someone explain why i am getting the above warnings and how can i resolve it

Answer (score 1):

The [introduction](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) described the function of `parent`. And the warnings states you should not use these dependencies witch are already defined in the parent, but with different version.

You can remove the `version` section for the mentioned dependencies, like

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: you mean i should just keep the spring-boot-starter-parent dependency?

Comment: No he meant to remove the `<version>..</version>` tag from the junit dependency so the version is controlled by the parent...